# Copy function to certain memory address

Tags: c, assembly

Let's say I've such function in certain memory address (for ex. 0x643795):

```
mov     ecx, [esp+4]
mov     eax, [ecx+19Ch]
and     byte ptr [eax+24h], 0
mov     ecx, [ecx+60h]
mov     [eax+2Ch], ecx
retn
```

Now, I would like to know, if there's any single way, to change this function, on this address with for ex. such thing:

```
mov ecx, [esp+8]
mov ecx, [ecx+19Ch]
retn
```

So, I'll be able to change function in certain address, with my own code (I'm mainly interested in C solution).

Comment: Yes, provided that the code is loaded at a writable location.  Just make an `unsigned char *` to it and overwrite the bytes.

Comment: Yeah, but instead of patching certain bytes, I would like to know, if there's a solution to "parse" the whole code I have, on this address.

Comment: Use an assembler (library).

Comment: I actually wonder how assembler library could help me to allocate my code in certain memory address, could you please describe it a little bit more?

Comment: Where is the function placed? Is it a writable memory? If yes you can simply use `memcpy(address_of_function, address_of_new_function, sizeof(new_function));`

Comment: Wow! Thanks, didn't thought of it! Great! Thank you very much!

Comment: I seriously doubt that `sizeof(new_function)` will return anything other than the native pointer size (usually 4 on most systems).

Comment: @LPs, surely `sizeof(new_function)` gives the size of a *pointer* to the function, not of the code for the function, yes?  Or do you know something about that that I don't?

Comment: @JohnBollinger It is a very general comment, not an answer. I was thinking about an array with the HEX code of function, hacking style ;). For a different solution size of `new_function` cannot be retrieve with `sizeof`, as you already well know.

Comment: @abelenky see what I wrote to John. BTW I didn't answered to the question to be general. With `sizeof(new_function)` I meant amount of bytes to be copied.

Comment: It may be worth noting that in general a function is **not** in a writable area of memory. If your intent is to patch something on the fly, you may need to do some more work.

Comment: There's no such thing as "C solution" for this. Any solution will be absolutely platform-specific and platform-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

C solution, but be careful, do not forget about nop aligment:

```
#include <windows.h>

__declspec(naked) void code()
{
    _asm
    {
        mov ecx, dword ptr [esp + 8]
        mov ecx, dword ptr [ecx + 19Ch]
        retn
    }
}

__declspec(naked) void code_end()
{
    _asm{nop}
}


int main()
{
    LPVOID MesBox_addr = GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA("user32.dll"), "MessageBoxA");

    DWORD dwOld;
    VirtualProtect(MesBox_addr, (DWORD)&code_end - (DWORD)&code, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOld);
    CopyMemory(MesBox_addr, (LPVOID)&code, (DWORD)&code_end - (DWORD)&code);

    MessageBoxA(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a "Windows solution" more than it is a "C solution". Of course, there's no such thing as "C solution" for this problem.

Comment: You are right. But if he is using IA-32, not AT&T, i think it's not a unix platform.